# unintalloing NB9.0 on Win10

Tags: netbeans

Win10-64
cygwin

ControlPanel->Apps does not show Netbeans 9.0 (although it does show Netbeans 8.2).

find /c/PrgoramData/Netbeans/* -iname 'unin*' was unable to find an uninstall executable.

So, is there some way to use a program to uninstall NB 9.0 or can I just delete the Netbeans directory?

thanks

Comment: Just delete the directory

Answer (score 1):

There is no installer/uninstaller for NetBeans 9/10. For NetBeans 11 there is an experimental one. There are currently some efforts to re-introduce an installer for the next release (see [here](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/1251af6dd35056081e204a6895649c4b78aeabfbef6e5b06174668a0@%3Cdev.netbeans.apache.org%3E) for more infos).

Like a_horse_with_no_name already mentioned just delete the NetBeans directory. Additionally you might want to delete (on Windows):

- C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\9.0
- C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\9.0

Comment: Hah. Just as I thought. It's easy.